# Unity www Loading local audio in iOS error

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

Error: Cannot create FMOD::Sound instance for resource \270,\216, (Operation could not be performed because specified sound/DSP connection is not ready. )

iOS Local audio path：var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A8A2C6B9-90CB-4400-A3E3-5B531CE92D45/Library/Caches/GHmsc/b18156b9-2085-4117-9c42-625ec415b691.mp3

```
IEnumerator LoadAudio()
{
    www = new WWW("file://" + "var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A8A2C6B9-90CB-4400-A3E3-5B531CE92D45/Library/Caches/GHmsc/b18156b9-2085-4117-9c42-625ec415b691.mp3");
    yield return www;
    if (www.error == null)
    {
        AudioClip audio = GetComponent<AudioClip>();
        audio = www.audioClip;

    }

}
```

The version used is 5.3.5

Comment: This code should not even compile. Please paste the code like it is from your Editor. Assuming that `cc type == AudioClip`, `cc.Play()` should not compile....

Comment: This is the c # language, but I will not js

Comment: It doesn't matter if C# or Js. The code in your question should not compile. You say you have you have run-time error but how we tell since your code will cause compile time error.....

Comment: Are you checking `isReadyToPlay` before playing the `AudioClip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be a bug. You can read more about it here:

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-audio-with-streaming-load-type-does-not-play-on-some-devices-running-ios-10

Comment: Thank you, but I can not find the version 5.3.8 is not on the line?

Comment: The latest is 5.4.3 and can be downloaded from https://unity3d.com/get-unity/update